# Hiding WPF controls from toolbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to hide some of the Controls from showing in Visual studio Toolbox. Then when I searched for how to do that and I found this:

[WPF and ToolboxItem(false)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545388/wpf-and-toolboxitemfalse)

But I am not able to find Microsoft.Windows.Design.dll assembly to use Microsoft.Windows.Design namespace which contains this **ToolboxBrowsableAttribute** class

I am using VS 2013 IDE. I could find two assemblies similar to that in Extensions, but they are not helping. I added **Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction** assembly as it contains definition for **ToolboxBrowsableAttribute** class, but looks like this assembly is targeted for X86 platform and I am receiving the below warning:

There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out another approach to hide the WPF controls from appearing in the toolbox:

using **[DesignTimeVisible(false)]** attribute which is available in **System.ComponentModel** namespace